# MySQL - How can I get names of all students that were taught by teacher with name John?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join

How can I get all students names that were taught by the teacher with name John?

**student**

```
id
name
```

**student_has_teacher**

```
teacher_id
student_id
```

**teacher**

```
id
name
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Sounds like homework. Presumably you have a table of students and teachers. How about you look into the JOIN and WHERE statements?

Comment: Clearly you need to look into the INNER JOHN clause.

Comment: +1 for INNER JOHN.  Genuine lol!

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [Inner Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join). An Inner Join creates a new result table by combining column values of two tables based upon a join-predicate. Your query should probably look something like this:

```
SELECT      student.name
FROM        student
INNER JOIN  student_has_teacher ON (student_has_teacher.student_id = student.id)
INNER JOIN  teacher ON (teacher.id = student_has_teacher.teacher_id)
WHERE       teacher.name = 'John';
```

Comment: Of course you should not be using select *, that too is poor technique. It wastes server and network resources when you have a join. Don't encourage the use of poor technique.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.name
FROM student s 
    INNER JOIN student_has_teacher st ON s.id = st.student_id
    INNER JOIN teacher t ON st.teacher_id = t.id
WHERE t.name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query below assumes there may be duplicate records in student_has_teacher, and will avoid causing duplicate results even if that is the case:

```
select s.id, s.name
from student s
where s.id in (
    select sht.student_id 
    from student_has_teacher sht
    inner join teacher on sht.teacher_id = t.id
    where t.name = 'John'
)
```

If there are not duplicates in student_has_teacher, then you can use joins, like this:

```
select s.id, s.name
from student s
inner join student_has_teacher sht on s.id = sht.student_id
inner join teacher on sht.teacher_id = t.id
where t.name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

the following query will give you the desired result for sure.

```
SELECT st.name
FROM student AS st
LEFT JOIN student_has_teacher AS stte ON st.id = stte.student_id
LEFT JOIN teacher AS te ON stte.teacher_id = te.id
WHERE te.name = "John"
```